# Convert results in python to dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

help to convert a python code results, where its finding the number of time the vowel appears in a string to dictionary?

```
count = 0
s = "apple"
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
  for char in s:
   if char in vowels:
    count += 1
  print ('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

The result should be:
for apple: {'a' : 1, 'e' : 1}

Comment: What dictionary are you trying to get? From a vowel to the number of time it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple change like this would do: instead of incrementing `count += 1`, increment directly on a dictionary:

```
count = 0
s = "apple"
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
vowels_dict = {}
for char in s:
   if char in vowels:
       if char in vowels_dict:
           vowels_dict[char] +=1
       else:
           vowels_dict[char] = 1

print (vowels_dict)
```

Comment: Your indention is off and nothing is in `vowels_dict` originally so how are you going to add anything to a non-existant key?

Comment: @PythonMaster: Notice the `else` has `vowels_dict[char] = 1`.  The colon in `else` was left out, but the logic of the code is correct.  I've fixed it, now.

Comment: Now it makes more sense, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make `vowels` into a dictionary . We will need a second one to hold on to the matches we make in the first loop:

```
s = "apples"
vowels = dict.fromkeys('aeiou', 0)
matches = {}
```

We will need to modify your `for` loop slightly to increment the *value* of the corresponding *key* (the vowels):

```
for char in s:
    if char in vowels:
        vowels[char] += 1
```

The `for` loop above checks if `char` is a vowel (or put simply, is one of the keys found in `vowels`). If it is, we increment the corresponding key's value by 1. For example, if `char` was "a", the `if` statement would return True and the key ("a")'s value (the integer after the colon) will increase by one. Now all we need is to put all the keys whose value is over 0 into the `matches` dictionary:

```
for vowel in vowels:
    if vowels[vowel] < 1:    # The vowel didn't appear in the word
        continue
    else:
        matches[str(vowel)] = vowels[vowel]
```

The last line creates a new key for the `matches` dictionary (the `matches[str(vowel)]` part) then assigns the value of the new key equal to the value of the respective key in the `vowels` dictionary (the `= vowels[vowel]` part). Now all we need to do is to print out the `matches` dictionary:

```
print matches
```

Full code:

```
count = 0
s = "apple"
vowels = dict.fromkeys('aeiou', 0)
matches = {}
for char in s:
    if char in vowels:
        vowels[char] += 1
for vowel in vowels:
    if vowels[vowel] < 1:
        continue
    else:
        matches[str(vowel)] = vowels[vowel]

print matches
```

Comment: Your vowels dictionary could be instantiated more simply with `dict.fromkeys('aeiou', 0)`